# How iterate inside for in UIView elements

Tags: objective-c, for-in-loop

I have this code but i cant iterate inside a UIScroll for my main UIView (self) elements

how iterate for all elements in a main UIView

```
 for (UIView *objet in self.view.subviews) {

        if ([objet isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {

             [objet setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

        }

    }
```

And I've also tried this but does not work.

```
for (UIView *objeto in super.self.view.subviews) { 

    if ([objeto isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {

         [objeto setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

        }

 }
```

Comment: I think call `super.self` is nonsense.

Comment: hehehe ok. i dont have more ideas to resolve this

Comment: Try mine. Id update my answer. Refresh site and look at him.

Comment: Are the buttons subviews of one of your subviews by chance? If so you'd need to check them as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for (UIView *objet in self.view.subviews) {

    if ([objet isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        UIButton *aButton = (UIButton *)objet;

        [aButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

    }

}
```

The compiler will probably be much happier with you (and you won't be seeing warnings about calling "`setBackgroundColor`" on a UIView).

Answer (score 0):

How you creating the subviews? You can `setTag:` for each, and then use something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < subviewsCount; ++i)
{
    [[superview viewWithTag:i] setBackgroundColor: [UIColor blueColor]];
}
```

Other way - put all subviews into NSMutableArray. Then you can use:

```
for (UIView *currentView in arrayOfSubviews)
{
    [currentView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor blueColor]];
}
```